# Javascript oad in HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: jquery, ssl, https

I have a script that loads from twitter (im not fully aware of exactly what it takes from their CDN), but it is part of my CMS and it loads from HTTP instead of HTTPS giving me mixed content warnings.  The script mentioned causing this issue is https://www.cobaltunlock.com/includes/js/jquery.js .  Like i said im not fully aware what exactly this script does, im not familair with javascript, but i need it to load it in HTTPS not HTTP.
here is the code: 
`{for(var a=0,b;(b=this[a])!=null;a++){b.nodeType===1&&f.cleanData(b.getElementsByTagName(""));while(b.firstChild)b.removeChild(b.firstChild)}return this},clone:function(a,b){a=a==null?!1:a,b=b==null?a:b;return this.map(function(){return f.clone(this,a,b)})},html:function(a){if(a===b)return this[0]&&this[0].nodeType===1?this[0].innerHTML.replace(W,""):null;if(typeof a=="string"&&!ba.test(a)&&(f.support.leadingWhitespace||!X.test(a))&&!bg[(Z.exec(a)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()]){a=a.replace(Y,"");try{for(var c=0,d=this.length;c")),this[c].innerHTML=a)}catch(e){this.empty().append(a)}}else f.isFunction(a)?this.each(function(b){var c=f(this);c.html(a.call(this,b,c.html()))}):this.empty().append(a);return this},replaceWith:function(a){if(this[0]&&this[0].parentNode){if(f.isFunction(a))return this.each(function(b){var c=f(this),d=c.html();c.replaceWith(a.call(this,b,d))});typeof a!="string"&&(a=f(a).detach());return this.each(function(){var b=this.nextSibling,c=this.parentNode;f(this).remove(),b?f(b).before(a):f(c).append(a)})}return this.length?this.pushStack(f(f.isFunction(a)?a():a),"replaceWith",a):this},detach:function(a){return this.remove(a,!0)},domManip:function(a,c,d){var e,g,h,i,j=a[0],k=[];if(!f.support.checkClone&&arguments.length===3&&typeof j=="string"&&bd.test(j))return this.each(function(){f(this).domManip(a,c,d,!0)});if(f.isFunction(j))return this.each(function(e){var g=f(this);a[0]=j.call(this,e,c?g.html():b),g.domManip(a,c,d)});if(this[0]){i=j&&j.parentNode,f.support.parentNode&&i&&i.nodeType===11&&i.childNodes.length===this.length?e={fragment:i}:e=f.buildFragment(a,this,k),h=e.fragment,h.childNodes.length===1?g=h=h.firstChild:g=h.firstChild;if(g){c=c&&f.nodeName(g,"tr");for(var l=0,m=this.length,n=m-1;l1&&lb;return this}for(var h=0,i=e.length;h0?this.clone(!0):this).get();f(e[h])b,d=d.concat(j)}return this.pushStack(d,a,e.selector)}}),f.extend({clone:function(a,b,c){var d,e,g,h=f.support.html5Clone||!bc.test("<"+a.nodeName)?a.cloneNode(!0):bo(a);if((!f.support.noCloneEvent||!f.support.noCloneChecked)&&(a.nodeType===1||a.nodeType===11)&&!f.isXMLDoc(a)){bk(a,h),d=bl(a),e=bl(h);for(g=0;d[g];++g)e[g]&&bk(d[g],e[g])}if(b){bj(a,h);if(c){d=bl(a),e=bl(h);for(g=0;d[g];++g)bj(d[g],e[g])}}d=e=null;return h},clean:function(a,b,d,e){var g;b=b||c,typeof b.createElement=="undefined"&&(b=b.ownerDocument||b[0]&&b[0].ownerDocument||c);var h=[],i;for(var j=0,k;(k=a[j])!=null;j++){typeof k=="number"&&(k+="");if(!k)continue;if(typeof k=="string")if(!_.test(k))k=b.createTextNode(k);else{k=k.replace(Y,"");var l=(Z.exec(k)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase(),m=bg[l]||bg.default,n=m[0],o=b.createElement("div");b===c?bh.appendChild(o):U(b).appendChild(o),o.innerHTML=m[1]+k+m[2];while(n--)o=o.lastChild;if(!f.support.tbody){var p=$.test(k),q=l==="table"&&!p?o.firstChild&&o.firstChild.childNodes:m[1]===""&&!p?o.childNodes:[];for(i=q.length-1;i>=0;--i)f.nodeName(q[i],"tbody")&&!q[i].childNodes.length&&q[i].parentNode.removeChild(q[i])}!f.support.leadingWhitespace&&X.test(k)&&o.insertBefore(b.createTextNode(X.exec(k)[0]),o.firstChild),k=o.childNodes}var r;if(!f.support.appendChecked)if(k[0]&&typeof (r=k.length)=="number")for(i=0;i=0)return b+"px"}}}),f.support.opacity||(f.cssHooks.opacity={get:function(a,b){return br.test((b&&a.currentStyle?a.currentStyle.filter:a.style.filter)||"")?parseFloat(RegExp.$1)/100+"":b?"1":""},set:function(a,b){var c=a.style,d=a.currentStyle,e=f.isNumeric(b)?"alpha(opacity="+b*100+")":"",g=d&&d.filter||c.filter||"";c.zoom=1;if(b>=1&&f.trim(g.replace(bq,""))===""){c.removeAttribute("filter");if(d&&!d.filter)return}c.filter=bq.test(g)?g.replace(bq,e):g+" "+e}}),f(function(){f.support.reliableMarginRight||(f.cssHooks.marginRight={get:function(a,b){var c;f.swap(a,{display:"inline-block"},function(){b?c=bz(a,"margin-right","marginRight"):c=a.style.marginRight});return c}})}),c.defaultView&&c.defaultView.getComputedStyle&&(bA=function(a,b){var c,d,e;b=b.replace(bs,"-$1").toLowerCase(),(d=a.ownerDocument.defaultView)&&(e=d.getComputedStyle(a,null))&&(c=e.getPropertyValue(b),c===""&&!f.contains(a.ownerDocument.documentElement,a)&&(c=f.style(a,b)));return c}),c.documentElement.currentStyle&&(bB=function(a,b){var c,d,e,f=a.currentStyle&&a.currentStyle[b],g=a.style;f===null&&g&&(e=g[b])&&(f=e),!bt.test(f)&&bu.test(f)&&(c=g.left,d=a.runtimeStyle&&a.runtimeStyle.left,d&&(a.runtimeStyle.left=a.currentStyle.left),g.left=b==="fontSize"?"1em":f||0,f=g.pixelLeft+"px",g.left=c,d&&(a.runtimeStyle.left=d));return f===""?"auto":f}),bz=bA||bB,f.expr&&f.expr.filters&&(f.expr.filters.hidden=function(a){var b=a.offsetWidth,c=a.offsetHeight;return b===0&&c===0||!f.support.reliableHiddenOffsets&&(a.style&&a.style.display||f.css(a,"display"))==="none"},f.expr.filters.visible=function(a){return!f.expr.filters.hidden(a)});var bD=/%20/g,bE=/[]$/,bF=/\r?\n/g,bG=/#.*$/,bH=/^(.*?):[ \t]*([^\r\n]*)\r?$/mg,bI=/^(?:color|date|datetime|datetime-local|email|hidden|month|number|password|range|search|tel|text|time|url|week)$/i,bJ=/^(?:about|app|app-storage|.+-extension|file|res|widget):$/,bK=/^(?:GET|HEAD)$/,bL=/^///,bM=/\?/,bN=/)<[^<]*)*</script>/gi,bO=/^(?:select|textarea)/i,bP=/\s+/,bQ=/([?&])=[^&]/,bR=/^([\w+.-]+:)(?://([^/?#:])(?::(\d+))?)?/,bS=f.fn.load,bT={},bU={},bV,bW,bX=["/"]+[""];try{bV=e.href}catch(bY){bV=c.createElement("a"),bV.href="",bV=bV.href}bW=bR.exec(bV.toLowerCase())||[],f.fn.extend({load:function(a,c,d){if(typeof a!="string"&&bS)return bS.apply(this,arguments);if(!this.length)return this;var e=a.indexOf(" ");if(e>=0){var g=a.slice(e,a.length);a=a.slice(0,e)}var h="GET";c&&(f.isFunction(c)?(d=c,c=b):typeof c=="object"&&(c=f.param(c,f.ajaxSettings.traditional),h="POST"));var i=this;f.ajax({url:a,type:h,dataType:"html",data:c,complete:function(a,b,c){c=a.responseText,a.isResolved()&&(a.done(function(a){c=a}),i.html(g?f("").append(c.replace(bN,"")).find(g):c)),d&&i.each(d,[c,b,a])}});return this},serialize:function(){return f.param(this.serializeArray())},serializeArray:function(){return this.map(function(){return this.elements?f.makeArray(this.elements):this}).filter(function(){return this.name&&!this.disabled&&(this.checked||bO.test(this.nodeName)||bI.test(this.type))}).map(function(a,b){var c=f(this).val();return c==null?null:f.isArray(c)?f.map(c,function(a,c){return{name:b.name,value:a.replace(bF,"\r\n")}}):{name:b.name,value:c.replace(bF,"\r\n")}}).get()}}),f.each("ajaxStart ajaxStop ajaxComplete ajaxError ajaxSuccess ajaxSend".split(" "),function(a,b){f.fn[b]=function(a){return this.on(b,a)}}),f.each(["get","post"],function(a,c){f[c]=function(a,d,e,g){f.isFunction(d)&&(g=g||e,e=d,d=b);return f.ajax({type:c,url:a,data:d,success:e,dataType:g})}}),f.extend({getScript:function(a,c){return f.get(a,b,c,"script")},getJSON:function(a,b,c){return f.get(a,b,c,"json")},ajaxSetup:function(a,b){b?b_(a,f.ajaxSettings):(b=a,a=f.ajaxSettings),b_(a,b);return a},ajaxSettings:{url:bV,isLocal:bJ.test(bW[1]),global:!0,type:"GET",contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",processData:!0,async:!0,accepts:{xml:"application/xml, text/xml",html:"text/html",text:"text/plain",json:"application/json, text/javascript","":bX},contents:{xml:/xml/,html:/html/,json:/json/},responseFields:{xml:"responseXML",text:"responseText"},converters:{" text":a.String,"text html":!0,"text json":f.parseJSON,"text xml":f.parseXML},flatOptions:{context:!0,url:!0}},ajaxPrefilter:bZ(bT),ajaxTransport:bZ(bU),ajax:function(a,c){function w(a,c,l,m){if(s!==2){s=2,q&&clearTimeout(q),p=b,n=m||"",v.readyState=a>0?4:0;var o,r,u,w=c,x=l?cb(d,v,l):b,y,z;if(a>=200&&a<300||a===304){if(d.ifModified){if(y=v.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"))f.lastModified[k]=y;if(z=v.getResponseHeader("Etag"))f.etag[k]=z}if(a===304)w="notmodified",o=!0;else try{r=cc(d,x),w="success",o=!0}catch(A){w="parsererror",u=A}}else{u=w;if(!w||a)w="error",a<0&&(a=0)}v.status=a,v.statusText=""+(c||w),o?h.resolveWith(e,[r,w,v]):h.rejectWith(e,[v,w,u]),v.statusCode(j),j=b,t&&g.trigger("ajax"+(o?"Success":"Error"),[v,d,o?r:u]),i.fireWith(e,[v,w]),t&&(g.trigger("ajaxComplete",[v,d]),--f.active||f.event.trigger("ajaxStop"))}}typeof a=="object"&&(c=a,a=b),c=c||{};var d=f.ajaxSetup({},c),e=d.context||d,g=e!==d&&(e.nodeType||e instanceof f)?f(e):f.event,h=f.Deferred(),i=f.Callbacks("once memory"),j=d.statusCode||{},k,l={},m={},n,o,p,q,r,s=0,t,u,v={readyState:0,setRequestHeader:function(a,b){if(!s){var c=a.toLowerCase();a=m[c]=m[c]||a,l[a]=b}return this},getAllResponseHeaders:function(){return s===2?n:null},getResponseHeader:function(a){var c;if(s===2){if(!o){o={};while(c=bH.exec(n))o[c[1].toLowerCase()]=c[2]}c=o[a.toLowerCase()]}return c===b?null:c},overrideMimeType:function(a){s||(d.mimeType=a);return this},abort:function(a){a=a||"abort",p&&p.abort(a),w(0,a);return this}};h.promise(v),v.success=v.done,v.error=v.fail,v.complete=i.add,v.statusCode=function(a){if(a){var b;if(s<2)for(b in a)j[b]=[j[b],a[b]];else b=a[v.status],v.then(b,b)}return this},d.url=((a||d.url)+"").replace(bG,"").replace(bL,bW[1]+"//"),d.dataTypes=f.trim(d.dataType||"").toLowerCase().split(bP),d.crossDomain==null&&(r=bR.exec(d.url.toLowerCase()),d.crossDomain=!(!r||r[1]==bW[1]&&r[2]==bW[2]&&(r[3]||(r[1]==="http:"?80:443))==(bW[3]||(bW[1]==="http:"?80:443)))),d.data&&d.processData&&typeof d.data!="string"&&(d.data=f.param(d.data,d.traditional)),b$(bT,d,c,v);if(s===2)return!1;t=d.global,d.type=d.type.toUpperCase(),d.hasContent=!bK.test(d.type),t&&f.active++===0&&f.event.trigger("ajaxStart");if(!d.hasContent){d.data&&(d.url+=(bM.test(d.url)?"&":"?")+d.data,delete d.data),k=d.url;if(d.cache===!1){var x=f.now(),y=d.url.replace(bQ,"$1_="+x);d.url=y+(y===d.url?(bM.test(d.url)?"&":"?")+"_="+x:"")}}(d.data&&d.hasContent&&d.contentType!==!1||c.contentType)&&v.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",d.contentType),d.ifModified&&(k=k||d.url,f.lastModified[k]&&v.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since",f.lastModified[k]),f.etag[k]&&v.setRequestHeader("If-None-Match",f.etag[k])),v.setRequestHeader("Accept",d.dataTypes[0]&&d.accepts[d.dataTypes[0]]?d.accepts[d.dataTypes[0]]+(d.dataTypes[0]!==""?", "+bX+"; q=0.01":""):d.accepts[""]);for(u in d.headers)v.setRequestHeader(u,d.headers[u]);if(d.beforeSend&&(d.beforeSend.call(e,v,d)===!1||s===2)){v.abort();return!1}for(u in{success:1,error:1,complete:1})vu;p=b$(bU,d,c,v);if(!p)w(-1,"No Transport");else{v.readyState=1,t&&g.trigger("ajaxSend",[v,d]),d.async&&d.timeout>0&&(q=setTimeout(function(){v.abort("timeout")},d.timeout));try{s=1,p.send(l,w)}catch(z){if(s<2)w(-1,z);else throw z}}return v},param:function(a,c){var d=[],e=function(a,b){b=f.isFunction(b)?b():b,d[d.length]=encodeURIComponent(a)+"="+encodeURIComponent(b)};c===b&&(c=f.ajaxSettings.traditional);if(f.isArray(a)||a.jquery&&!f.isPlainObject(a))f.each(a,function(){e(this.name,this.value)});else for(var g in a)ca(g,a[g],c,e);return d.join("&").replace(bD,"+")}}),f.extend({active:0,lastModified:{},etag:{}});var cd=f.now(),ce=/(\=)\?(&|$)|\?\?/i;f.ajaxSetup({jsonp:"callback",jsonpCallback:function(){return f.expando+"_"+cd++}}),f.ajaxPrefilter("json jsonp",function(b,c,d){var e=b.contentType==="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"&&typeof b.data=="string";if(b.dataTypes[0]==="jsonp"||b.jsonp!==!1&&(ce.test(b.url)||e&&ce.test(b.data))){var g,h=b.jsonpCallback=f.isFunction(b.jsonpCallback)?b.jsonpCallback():b.jsonpCallback,i=a[h],j=b.url,k=b.data,l="$1"+h+"$2";b.jsonp!==!1&&(j=j.replace(ce,l),b.url===j&&(e&&(k=k.replace(ce,l)),b.data===k&&(j+=(/\?/.test(j)?"&":"?")+b.jsonp+"="+h))),b.url=j,b.data=k,a[h]=function(a){g=[a]},d.always(function(){a[h]=i,g&&f.isFunction(i)&&ah}),b.converters["script json"]=function(){g||f.error(h+" was not called");return g[0]},b.dataTypes[0]="json";return"script"}}),f.ajaxSetup({accepts:{script:"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript"},contents:{script:/javascript|ecmascript/},converters:{"text script":function(a){f.globalEval(a);return a}}}),f.ajaxPrefilter("script",function(a){a.cache===b&&(a.cache=!1),a.crossDomain&&(a.type="GET",a.global=!1)}),f.ajaxTransport("script",function(a){if(a.crossDomain){var d,e=c.head||c.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||c.documentElement;return{send:function(f,g){d=c.createElement("script"),d.async="async",a.scriptCharset&&(d.charset=a.scriptCharset),d.src=a.url,d.onload=d.onreadystatechange=function(a,c){if(c||!d.readyState||/loaded|complete/.test(d.readyState))d.onload=d.onreadystatechange=null,e&&d.parentNode&&e.removeChild(d),d=b,c||g(200,"success")},e.insertBefore(d,e.firstChild)},abort:function(){d&&d.onload(0,1)}}}});var cf=a.ActiveXObject?function(){for(var a in ch)cha}:!1,cg=0,ch;f.ajaxSettings.xhr=a.ActiveXObject?function(){return!this.isLocal&&ci()||cj()}:ci,function(a){f.extend(f.support,{ajax:!!a,cors:!!a&&"withCredentials"in a})}(f.ajaxSettings.xhr()),f.support.ajax&&f.ajaxTransport(function(c){if(!c.crossDomain||f.support.cors){var d;return{send:function(e,g){var h=c.xhr(),i,j;c.username?h.open(c.type,c.url,c.async,c.username,c.password):h.open(c.type,c.url,c.async);if(c.xhrFields)for(j in c.xhrFields)h[j]=c.xhrFields[j];c.mimeType&&h.overrideMimeType&&h.overrideMimeType(c.mimeType),!c.crossDomain&&!e["X-Requested-With"]&&(e["X-Requested-With"]="XMLHttpRequest");try{for(j in e)h.setRequestHeader(j,e[j])}catch(k){}h.send(c.hasContent&&c.data||null),d=function(a,e){var j,k,l,m,n;try{if(d&&(e||h.readyState===4)){d=b,i&&(h.onreadystatechange=f.noop,cf&&delete ch[i]);if(e)h.readyState!==4&&h.abort();else{j=h.status,l=h.getAllResponseHeaders(),m={},n=h.responseXML,n&&n.documentElement&&(m.xml=n),m.text=h.responseText;try{k=h.statusText}catch(o){k=""}!j&&c.isLocal&&!c.crossDomain?j=m.text?200:404:j===1223&&(j=204)}}}catch(p){e||g(-1,p)}m&&g(j,k,m,l)},!c.async||h.readyState===4?d():(i=++cg,cf&&(ch||(ch={},f(a).unload(cf)),ch[i]=d),h.onreadystatechange=d)},abort:function(){d&&d(0,1)}}}});var ck={},cl,cm,cn=/^(?:toggle|show|hide)$/,co=/^([+-]=)?([\d+.-]+)([a-z%])$/i,cp,cq=[["height","marginTop","marginBottom","paddingTop","paddingBottom"],["width","marginLeft","marginRight","paddingLeft","paddingRight"],["opacity"]],cr;f.fn.extend({show:function(a,b,c){var d,e;if(a||a===0)return this.animate(cu("show",3),a,b,c);for(var g=0,h=this.length;gb?"show":"hide"}):this.animate(cu("toggle",3),a,b,c);return this},fadeTo:function(a,b,c,d){return this.filter(":hidden").css("opacity",0).show().end().animate({opacity:b},a,c,d)},animate:function(a,b,c,d){function g(){e.queue===!1&&f._mark(this);var b=f.extend({},e),c=this.nodeType===1,d=c&&f(this).is(":hidden"),g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o;b.animatedProperties={};for(i in a){g=f.camelCase(i),i!==g&&(a[g]=a[i],delete a[i]),h=a[g],f.isArray(h)?(b.animatedProperties[g]=h[1],h=a[g]=h[0]):b.animatedProperties[g]=b.specialEasing&&b.specialEasing[g]||b.easing||"swing";if(h==="hide"&&d||h==="show"&&!d)return b.complete.call(this);c&&(g==="height"||g==="width")&&(b.overflow=[this.style.overflow,this.style.overflowX,this.style.overflowY],f.css(this,"display")==="inline"&&f.css(this,"float")==="none"&&(!f.support.inlineBlockNeedsLayout||cv(this.nodeName)==="inline"?this.style.display="inline-block":this.style.zoom=1))}b.overflow!=null&&(this.style.overflow="hidden");for(i in a)j=new f.fx(this,b,i),h=a[i],cn.test(h)?(o=f._data(this,"toggle"+i)||(h==="toggle"?d?"show":"hide":0),o?(f._data(this,"toggle"+i,o==="show"?"hide":"show"),jo):jh):(k=co.exec(h),l=j.cur(),k?(m=parseFloat(k[2]),n=k[3]||(f.cssNumber[i]?"":"px"),n!=="px"&&(f.style(this,i,(m||1)+n),l=(m||1)/j.cur()*l,f.style(this,i,l+n)),k[1]&&(m=(k[1]==="-="?-1:1)*m+l),j.custom(l,m,n)):j.custom(l,h,""));return!0}var e=f.speed(b,c,d);if(f.isEmptyObject(a))return this.each(e.complete,[!1]);a=f.extend({},a);return e.queue===!1?this.each(g):this.queue(e.queue,g)},stop:function(a,c,d){typeof a!="string"&&(d=c,c=a,a=b),c&&a!==!1&&this.queue(a||"fx",[]);return this.each(function(){function h(a,b,c){var e=b[c];f.removeData(a,c,!0),e.stop(d)}var b,c=!1,e=f.timers,g=f._data(this);d||f._unmark(!0,this);if(a==null)for(b in g)g[b]&&g[b].stop&&b.indexOf(".run")===b.length-4&&h(this,g,b);else g[b=a+".run"]&&g[b].stop&&h(this,g,b);for(b=e.length;b--;)e[b].elem===this&&(a==null||e[b].queue===a)&&(d?eb:e[b].saveState(),c=!0,e.splice(b,1));(!d||!c)&&f.dequeue(this,a)})}}),f.each({slideDown:cu("show",1),slideUp:cu("hide",1),slideToggle:cu("toggle",1),fadeIn:{opacity:"show"},fadeOut:{opacity:"hide"},fadeToggle:{opacity:"toggle"}},function(a,b){f.fn[a]=function(a,c,d){return this.animate(b,a,c,d)}}),f.extend({speed:function(a,b,c){var d=a&&typeof a=="object"?f.extend({},a):{complete:c||!c&&b||f.isFunction(a)&&a,duration:a,easing:c&&b||b&&!f.isFunction(b)&&b};d.duration=f.fx.off?0:typeof d.duration=="number"?d.duration:d.duration in f.fx.speeds?f.fx.speeds[d.duration]:f.fx.speeds._default;if(d.queue==null||d.queue===!0)d.queue="fx";d.old=d.complete,d.complete=function(a){f.isFunction(d.old)&&d.old.call(this),d.queue?f.dequeue(this,d.queue):a!==!1&&f._unmark(this)};return d},easing:{linear:function(a,b,c,d){return c+d*a},swing:function(a,b,c,d){return(-Math.cos(a*Math.PI)/2+.5)*d+c}},timers:[],fx:function(a,b,c){this.options=b,this.elem=a,this.prop=c,b.orig=b.orig||{}}}),f.fx.prototype={update:function(){this.options.step&&this.options.step.call(this.elem,this.now,this),(f.fx.step[this.prop]||f.fx.step._default)(this)},cur:function(){if(this.elem[this.prop]!=null&&(!this.elem.style||this.elem.style[this.prop]==null))return this.elem[this.prop];var a,b=f.css(this.elem,this.prop);return isNaN(a=parseFloat(b))?!b||b==="auto"?0:b:a},custom:function(a,c,d){function h(a){return e.step(a)}var e=this,g=f.fx;this.startTime=cr||cs(),this.end=c,this.now=this.start=a,this.pos=this.state=0,this.unit=d||this.unit||(f.cssNumber[this.prop]?"":"px"),h.queue=this.options.queue,h.elem=this.elem,h.saveState=function(){e.options.hide&&f._data(e.elem,"fxshow"+e.prop)===b&&f._data(e.elem,"fxshow"+e.prop,e.start)},h()&&f.timers.push(h)&&!cp&&(cp=setInterval(g.tick,g.interval))},show:function(){var a=f._data(this.elem,"fxshow"+this.prop);this.options.orig[this.prop]=a||f.style(this.elem,this.prop),this.options.show=!0,a!==b?this.custom(this.cur(),a):this.custom(this.prop==="width"||this.prop==="height"?1:0,this.cur()),f(this.elem).show()},hide:function(){this.options.orig[this.prop]=f._data(this.elem,"fxshow"+this.prop)||f.style(this.elem,this.prop),this.options.hide=!0,this.custom(this.cur(),0)},step:function(a){var b,c,d,e=cr||cs(),g=!0,h=this.elem,i=this.options;if(a||e>=i.duration+this.startTime){this.now=this.end,this.pos=this.state=1,this.update(),i.animatedProperties[this.prop]=!0;for(b in i.animatedProperties)i.animatedProperties[b]!==!0&&(g=!1);if(g){i.overflow!=null&&!f.support.shrinkWrapBlocks&&f.each(["","X","Y"],function(a,b){h.style["overflow"+b]=i.overflow[a]}),i.hide&&f(h).hide();if(i.hide||i.show)for(b in i.animatedProperties)f.style(h,b,i.orig[b]),f.removeData(h,"fxshow"+b,!0),f.removeData(h,"toggle"+b,!0);d=i.complete,d&&(i.complete=!1,d.call(h))}return!1}i.duration==Infinity?this.now=e:(c=e-this.startTime,this.state=c/i.duration,this.pos=f.easingi.animatedProperties[this.prop],this.now=this.start+(this.end-this.start)*this.pos),this.update();return!0}},f.extend(f.fx,{tick:function(){var a,b=f.timers,c=0;for(;c-1,k={},l={},m,n;j?(l=e.position(),m=l.top,n=l.left):(m=parseFloat(h)||0,n=parseFloat(i)||0),f.isFunction(b)&&(b=b.call(a,c,g)),b.top!=null&&(k.top=b.top-g.top+m),b.left!=null&&(k.left=b.left-g.left+n),"using"in b?b.using.call(a,k):e.css(k)}},f.fn.extend({position:function(){if(!this[0])return null;var a=this[0],b=this.offsetParent(),c=this.offset(),d=cx.test(b[0].nodeName)?{top:0,left:0}:b.offset();c.top-=parseFloat(f.css(a,"marginTop"))||0,c.left-=parseFloat(f.css(a,"marginLeft"))||0,d.top+=parseFloat(f.css(b[0],"borderTopWidth"))||0,d.left+=parseFloat(f.css(b[0],"borderLeftWidth"))||0;return{top:c.top-d.top,left:c.left-d.left}},offsetParent:function(){return this.map(function(){var a=this.offsetParent||c.body;while(a&&!cx.test(a.nodeName)&&f.css(a,"position")==="static")a=a.offsetParent;return a})}}),f.each(["Left","Top"],function(a,c){var d="scroll"+c;f.fn[d]=function(c){var e,g;if(c===b){e=this[0];if(!e)return null;g=cy(e);return g?"pageXOffset"in g?g[a?"pageYOffset":"pageXOffset"]:f.support.boxModel&&g.document.documentElement[d]||g.document.body[d]:e[d]}return this.each(function(){g=cy(this),g?g.scrollTo(a?f(g).scrollLeft():c,a?c:f(g).scrollTop()):this[d]=c})}}),f.each(["Height","Width"],function(a,c){var d=c.toLowerCase();f.fn["inner"+c]=function(){var a=this[0];return a?a.style?parseFloat(f.css(a,d,"padding")):thisd:null},f.fn["outer"+c]=function(a){var b=this[0];return b?b.style?parseFloat(f.css(b,d,a?"margin":"border")):thisd:null},f.fn[d]=function(a){var e=this[0];if(!e)return a==null?null:this;if(f.isFunction(a))return this.each(function(b){var c=f(this);cd});if(f.isWindow(e)){var g=e.document.documentElement["client"+c],h=e.document.body;return e.document.compatMode==="CSS1Compat"&&g||h&&h["client"+c]||g}if(e.nodeType===9)return Math.max(e.documentElement["client"+c],e.body["scroll"+c],e.documentElement["scroll"+c],e.body["offset"+c],e.documentElement["offset"+c]);if(a===b){var i=f.css(e,d),j=parseFloat(i);return f.isNumeric(j)?j:i}return this.css(d,typeof a=="string"?a:a+"px")}}),a.jQuery=a.$=f,typeof define=="function"&&define.amd&&define.amd.jQuery&&define("jquery",[],function(){return f})})(window);`

Comment: Perhaps host the content of the file on your server or maybe append `https` instead of `http` to the reference?!

Comment: While I appreciate you put the code in for completeness, pasting such a lengthy piece of **minified** JavaScript code makes it completely unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

ok i found out what was wrong.  My plan was to find the HTTP and replace it with HTTPS, issue was with another script that this one called.  If it helps the script was older/modified by the devs who made my cms.  Thanks for everyone who did help, but I eventually found it throughout the scripts.